# Maintaining TestObjects in Object Repository vs Creating TestObjects dynamically in script - Katalon Studio

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

Initially when I started web automation using Katalon Studio, I was capturing objects, storing them in the **Object Repository** and then using them in my script. This was a bit of a hassle, now I put `id` tags on all the web elements that were most likely to be used from my web-app and I create objects in my script whenever I need them using this `CustomKeyword` I wrote:

```
/**
 *
 * @param buttonID
 * @return TestObject representing the newly created control
 */
@Keyword
public TestObject createControl(String controlID){
    TestObject newControl = new TestObject()
    WebUI.modifyObjectProperty(newControl, 'id', 'equals', controlID, true)
    return newControl
}
```

Even though this works, I want to know whether it is a good idea to not  have any objects in the **Object Repository**. Maintaining the object repository was a lot of work, that's why I turned to this method of doing things, but I am too new to **Katalon Studio** to know whether this is a good idea or not. I couldn't find any information about this in the official Katalon docs so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use your approach, as well. I usually use one line to create an object:

```
TestObject myObject = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'css selector')
```

Object repository just doesn't scale well. And it is very difficult to maintain.

There are interesting discussions on Katalon forum ([here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/can-i-work-without-object-repository/11644), [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/object-repository-recording-vs-manual-best-practise/11962) and especially [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/using-waitforelementpresent-without-an-object/10015), but there are more interesting discussions to look at).

The downside I can think of is if you are using the Page Object Model, you should keep the controls separate from the test itself. The solution would be to keep the selectors (id, name, css, xpath or other) in a separate file (like an excel table).

Comment: That is exactly why I don't want to keep an object repository, it doesn't make sense for a larger project. One question, the way you create your object, where would I add the ID?  so in my case 'css' would be 'id' and 'css selector' would be the id value I want? Is that correct?

Comment: Sure, that would probably work. If not, you could do `.addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, '#yourID')`.

Comment: Ceck out also https://api-docs.katalon.com/studio/v4.8.0/api/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/TestObjectProperty.html.

Comment: `.addProperty('id', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'myID')` worked

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your purpose and skills.
Saving object repository will help user having a visual view of how the object is stored. It also helps to store multiple attributes, which can be included or excluded with a single click. These attributes can be generated by Spy or Record Tools.
Your coding approach also works if you know programming. However, you have to decide the locator yourself. If the selected locator does not work anymore, you have to create another one. While in the object repository, if the id changed, a testers case choose the class and other attributes

Comment: I understand what you are saying but **Object Repository** just doesn't scale for me, it requires too much maintenance since the size of my project is very large compared to other Katalon projects. I guess as long as I keep the IDs consistent, I shouldn't run into a problem.

Comment: It is correct if you could the id consistent. However, if you cannot decide that rule, development team can change it unexpectedly.